# How to get or extract the link path for terms in View

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have created a Taxonomy Term view in Drupal 7,  and list out all my terms through "Taxonomy term: Name" field.

Now, I wonder how to extract the link path of each term so that I can reconstruct and adding the passing value through the url.

e.g.

```
http://www.domain.com/fruit/apple?quantity=100
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution will be:

1. Use "pathauto" to generate path for term pages (taxonomy/term/term_id => fruit/apple)
2. Use "global redirect" to force default path to custom paths
3. In your View build the URL like taxonomy/term/term_id?quantity=100 and should be translated at rendering time to fruit/apple?quantity=100

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! It works!

Actually without using "global redirect", the "taxonomy/term/[tid]?quantity=100" applied in View's field link path will still rendered to "fruit/apple?quantity=100" automatically. I guess the Pathauto do the magic. 

However, if I enable "global redirect", when typing the "taxonomy/term/1" in the url manually, it will automatically force default path to custom path "fruit/apple". Great thanks!

Comment: Glad to know it works for you.