# How to use a term's Pathauto URL in Views so the path can be rewritten?

Tags: views

I have a node view. I need to create a link to a term that the node it tagged with, but also add an additional part to this URL. So I need something like mysite.com/term-url/additional-bit

For SEO purposes I dont want to link to mysite.com/taxonomy/term/term_id?/additional-bit as is the solution below. Instead I want the nice pathauto url.

[How to get or extract the link path for terms in View](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38832/how-to-get-or-extract-the-link-path-for-terms-in-view)

Note, the reason that the url mysite.com/term-url/additional-bit works is that im using the sub-pathauto module https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto

Comment: Just to confirm: you do know that this url you want to link to won't actually point at a valid page without some additional configuration / code?

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong I not sure what you mean? I already have a working link using the term ID. So if the ID is 3 the path is /taxonomy/term/3/additional-bit. However I want to use the nice Pathauto path for the link.

Comment: If the path alias for a taxonomy term is 'pretty-path' then that will point to the taxonomy term page 'taxonomy/term/nnn'. But by default 'pretty-path/additional' will not point to 'taxonomy/term/nnn/additional'. Try it and see.

Comment: Im pointing to this: taxonomy/term/ID/additional and it works. At that path is a View page which uses the path (with the term ID as a token) and I make the pretty path works with Sub-pathauto https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Ive updated my question.

Comment: Great, I was referring to the default behaviour which confuses some people. If you have subpathauto installed, that's fine.